# c# - Iterate through dictionary and attach items to object

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have an entity framework object "user". I am passing variables in a dictionary to update the user with. I want to iterate through the dictionary items and attach them to the entity framework object.

So if an item has an id it will be update, else it will be inserted

**Dictionary Items:**

```
Dictionary<string, string> updateItems = new Dictionary<string, string>();
updateItems.Add("column1", "value1");
updateItems.Add("column2", "value2");
```

**Function:**

```
public static void markPost(Dictionary<string, string> data)
{
  using (var db = new DB())
  {
    var user = new user();   

    if (data.ContainsKey("id"))
    {          
      user = db.user.Find(Int32.Parse(data["id"])); 
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in data)
    {
      if (!entry.Key.Equals("id"))
      {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = user.GetType().GetProperty(entry.Key);
        propertyInfo.SetValue(user, entry.Value, null); 
      }          
    }

    if (!data.ContainsKey("id"))
    {
      db.user.Add(user);
    } 

    db.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: So, you're trying to update a property of `user`...And to find that property name you're using a string to try and find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your foreach loop, try

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = user.GetType().GetProperty(entry.Key);
propertyInfo.SetValue(user, entry.Value, null);  //Assumes the value is of the same type as the property.
```

You will need a using directive for System.Reflection.